# What does "Tell me about it" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> **John:** "I had a rough day."
>
> **Mary:** "Tell me about it."

What does "Tell me about it" mean?

Mary's statement doesn't sound sincere to me.

Comment: It's not a statement but an imperative, and it's not meant to be sincere, if that's what you mean. "You don't need to tell me because I've had a similar experience."

Comment: It's genuinely sarcastic, but friendly for being so standard. It does not mean *I don't want to hear about your boring rough day*, only *Yeah, I got it already*.

Comment: It is a colloquial idiom. Meaning: You are not telling me anything I don't already know.

Comment: @KateBunting I meant 'sincere', not 'genuine'. I've edited my post.

Comment: Exactly the same idiomatic sense *(I already know - **and agree**)* is conveyed by [***You're telling me!***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22You%27re+telling+me+said%22) Plus there's also ***Tell me something I don't know***, but that one's often more perfunctory / dismissive, so should be used with care.

Comment: If said kindly, it could mean what it appears to mean, i.e. 'tell me about your rough day, so that I may comfort you', or if said sarcastically I suppose it can mean 'Don't whine to me. I have had a rough day too'. It could also convey rueful agreement - e.g. Person A: Our boss is a toss-pot. Person B: Tell me about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(A) "tell me about it!"**

> used to say that you feel the same way or have had the same experience:
>
> > "He's driving me crazy with his stupid jokes."
> > "Tell me about it!"

Check here :
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-me-about-it

**(B) "tell me about it"**

> informal  idiom
> used to say that one understands what someone is talking about because one has had the same or a similar experience
>
> > "Something is wrong with that computer."
> > "Yeah, tell me about it. I can never get it to work properly."

Available here :
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tell%20me%20about%20it

**(C) "tell me about it"**

> A way of saying you agree with someone.
>
> > Tom: Man, what a rough day.
> > Tim: Tell me about it.

More here :
https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tell%20me%20about%20it

---

Basically , that **Idiom** is a way to say you know what the speaker wants to say , hence there is actually no necessity to say it.
It could be **sympathetic or sarcastic or friendly or facetious** , though it always **signals agreement** or concordance or concurrence or understanding. It is informal.

This video may be interesting or relevant to hear the Idiom used in various ways :

Song : "Tell Me About It"
Singer : "Tanya Tucker"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvH9Fg0pX0I